How do I make an overlay image fill the whole screen in CSS?
I am trying to have each of the four buttons on my index.html page display an image on hover that covers the whole screen. I've already figured out how to make an overlay display an image that is in front thanks to z-index and how to make the mouse cursor "see" through the overlay thanks to pointer-events. Now, the last thing I need to figure out is how to make the overlay image the same dimensions as the whole page.
So far I've tried scale, background-size: cover, transform, inline-size, and adjusting width and height. I've also done many web searches and haven't found anything that fixes my problem.
Here is my current relevant CSS code:
.audiobutton:hover, .photobutton:hover, .blenderbutton:hover, .videobutton:hover {
    background-size: cover;
}

#overlay.videobutton:hover {
    content: url(Renders/0004.png);
    /* background-size: cover; */
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    pointer-events: none;
}

&::after {
    content: url(Renders/0004.png);
    /* background-size: cover; */
    /* inline-size: 100svw; */
    /* block-size: 100svh; */
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 0;
}

#overlay:hover::after {
    content: url(Renders/0004.png);
    /* background-size: cover; */
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    inset: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    inline-size: (100svw);
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    block-size: (100svh);
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 1;
}

I also used some Javascript in my HTML for the videobutton, which I am using to test the code out for a solution before applying to the other buttons. This was how I got the overlay to only activate via hover.
<div class="image-container">
                        <a class="videobutton" href="video.html" onmouseover="on()" onmouseout="off()">
                            <img src="Renders/4-alpha-v2.png" alt="Podium for video">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="overlay" style="display:none;">
                        <img src="Renders/0004.png" alt="Overlay Image">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                function on() {
                    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
                }
                
                function off() {
                    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
                }
                </script>

Some of my CSS code is probably redundant, which I want to take care of once I have a solution to my overlay sizing issue.
